# Crash when use UIImagePickerController in iOS 13

Tags: ios, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

It work well in the other demo,but crash in my project. I google 'CAMPreviewViewController' but find nothing

```
UIImagePickerController * picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**CRASH**

> Assertion failure in -[CAMPreviewViewController _updateIndicatorsForMetadataObjectResults:viewType:viewClass:frameCallback:minimumAreaChangeThreshold:minimumAreaFractionChangeThreshold:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Camera/Camera-3602.9.230/CameraUI/Source/CAMPreviewViewController.m:1152

Comment: seems third party library causing this issue

Comment: maybe, it works good in iOS 12 and below.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

 @IBAction func takePhotoAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Add This to class as delegates 

 UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
```